# Problem with Postfix

Tags: email, unix, postfix, bugzilla

I have Postfix installed and Sendmail is not running. I try to send mail using `mail` but the following warning comes up and the mail doesn't get sent:

`postdrop: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory`

This is also confusing me:

```
[root@ars etc]# postfix start
postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system
[root@ars etc]# postfix stop
postfix/postfix-script: fatal: the Postfix mail system is not running
```

Please help! I need this working for Bugzilla.

Comment: Your Postfix installation wasn't done properly.  How was it installed?

Answer (score 6):

See below to resolve the following error:

```
postdrop: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
```

Run the following command as root:

```
mkfifo /var/spool/postfix/public/pickup
```

And then, restart the service :

```
service postfix restart
```

Comment: And what should the ownership and permissions be?

Answer (score 5):

Try running 'postfix check' to see if it finds any obvious errors which will include incorrect permissions and should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Is that an equivalent to "postsuper -s" (which is what I was going to suggest)?

Comment: No, `postsuper -s` does different things to `postfix check`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like either your /var/spool/postfix directory structure is missing a directory or the permissions are wrong.  On CentOS it looks like:

```
drwx------ 2 postfix root     4096 Jan  5 16:49 active
drwx------ 2 postfix root     4096 Dec 23 16:18 bounce
drwx------ 2 postfix root     4096 Aug 14  2008 corrupt
drwx------ 4 postfix root     4096 Dec 16 08:55 defer
drwx------ 4 postfix root     4096 Dec 16 08:55 deferred
drwx------ 2 postfix root     4096 Aug 14  2008 flush
drwx------ 2 postfix root     4096 Aug 14  2008 hold
drwx------ 2 postfix root     4096 Jan  5 16:49 incoming
drwx-wx--- 2 postfix postdrop 4096 Jan  5 16:49 maildrop
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root     4096 Dec 31 14:16 pid
drwx------ 2 postfix root     4096 Dec 31 14:39 private
drwx--x--- 2 postfix postdrop 4096 Dec 31 14:39 public
drwx------ 2 postfix root     4096 Aug 14  2008 saved
drwx------ 2 postfix root     4096 Aug 14  2008 trace
```

Check your /var/log/mail or /var/log/maillog file for error messages.
The reason you can't stop postfix is because it's not starting in the first place.

Comment: Mine looks exactly like that.

Comment: Then Postfix thinks it's queue directories should be somewhere else.  Post your complete `main.cf` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum reinstall postfix
service postfix restart
```